# Difference between 'prepositional phrase' and 'adjective phrase'?

Tags: phrases, functions

Can you please help me understand the difference between 'prepositional phrase' and 'adjective phrase'?

- He drives the car at high speed. (Prepositional phrase)
- The boy in the shop is my friend. (Adjective phrase)

My question is why these two phrases are different when both of them start with the preposition 'in'?

Comment: I think you are confusing word category (part of speech) with function. A preposition phrase (PP) has a preposition as its head, and an adjective phrase (AdjP) has an adjective as head. In your first example "at high speed" is a PP with "at" as head functioning as a modifier in clause structure. In the second, "in the shop" is also a PP, with "in" as head, and its functions is that of modifier of "boy".

Comment: Please don't ask unrelated questions in the same post.  If you have two questions, open two questions.

Answer (score 1):

As BillJ said, it's essential that you know the difference between syntactic categories and grammatical functions.

*A syntactic category* is merely the class of the expression. *At high speed* and *in the shop* are both prepositional phrases because they are headed by prepositions, which are *at* and *in*, respectively. They are clearly **not** adjective phrases because they are not headed by adjectives.<sup>*</sup>

*A grammatical function*, on the other hand, is a relational concept.<sup>†</sup> It expresses the relation between the syntactic category and the whole clause. A function is said to be realized by a word or phrase. In the first sentence, the prepositional phrase *realizes* the function of a *modifier* that modifies the verb *drive*.

In the second sentence, *in the shop* is a prepositional phrase realizing the same function. However, it's not modifying a verb; it's modifying the head noun *boy* in the noun phrase *the boy in the shop*.

---

<sup>*</sup> <sub>Though, adjectives can head a noun phrase in a *fused-head construction* as in 'The poor'.</sub>

<sup>†</sup> <sub>Huddleston, Rodney and Geoffrey K. Pullum. *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*, Cambridge University Press, 2005: 14.</sub>

Comment: Prepositional phrases don't modify verbs at all.

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh Hmm.. I wonder why not. In the OP, the PP clearly describes how he drives. So that means it's an adjunct of manner, which is a modiﬁer.

Comment: Adverbs modify verbs, adjectives modify nouns, prepositional phrase adds extra information to the clause as circumstances *He drives the car* or *He drives the car at high speed*. If you wanna modify the verb, you can say * He often/usually/ drives the car at high speed* for example.

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh PPs don't necessarily add circumstantial information. *I laugh at him*. *at him* is a PP but it heads the noun that's the 'patient' of the action.

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh Of course PPs can modify verbs, e.g. "I slept **in the garage**"; "In the UK, we drive **on the left**", to cite just two examples.

Comment: @user178049 *laugh at* is a phrasal verb, *him* is an object http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/laugh-at-sb-sth

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh No, it's a prepositional verb. *at him* is its complement because *at* is licensed by the verb *laugh*.

Comment: @BillJ Both of them are circumstances realized by prepositional phrases

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh They are adjuncts, i.e. modifiers of the verbs. There is no function called 'circumstances'. Circumstances in a clause are adjuncts (as opposed to complements) -- modifiers which can be realised by PPs.

Comment: I'm really not discussing to invalidate any point of view but to make it clear. I think someone has to confirm an answer coz the questioner would be confused after reading this.

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh The OP's question has been accurately answered by user 178049, and by me in my original comment to the OP. To repeat: "at high speed" is a PP in clause structure -- it modifies the VP "drives the car", and thus is semantically associated very closely with the verb. The PP is an adjunct of manner -- it tells us how he drives the car.

Comment: @BillJ according to Biber et al, Adjuncts could be adv.phrase, noun phrase, or prepositional phrase which contribute some additional ( but non-essential) information to the clause. *He walked to the shop*

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh Adjuncts are modifiers which are (usually) tightly integrated into clause structure. By definition, an adjunct is an optional element. In "The plane leaves **at 14.45**" the bit in bold is an adjunct, a syntactically optional element, but it will typically be a vital part of the information being conveyed.

Comment: I think your example here is different from the questions' above. I'm off for that but if I want to modify a verb in terms of *how* I'll use *often, usually, quickly, well, ....* not -by what means something happens- { circumstance of manner} .

Comment: @RolaAbu-Ghazaleh It was intended to demonstrate that adjuncts may be syntactically optional, but semantically vital. Now, that's an end to it.

Answer (score 0):

- **The prepositional phrase** ,which contains a preposition together with it's associated noun phrase, can either qualify the head word in a noun phrase or act as a circumstance in a clause**

  - **He drives the car at high speed**. The preposition phrase *at high speed*  acts as a circumstance of the clause. **The boy in the shop is my friend**. The preposition phrase here *in the shop* modifies the noun *the boy* by telling us which boy in particular is her/his friend. Like in *The image I remember is of a man **with a rifle*** {qualifier} / *The accused is supposed to have shot the victim **with a rifle*** { circumstance}. There's no an adjective phrase in your examples.

Comment: I know but here *in the shop* is a qualifier for the noun phrase *The boy*